# Only function definitions covered by unit testing python/flask backend

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I would like to start by saying that i am a beginner at both flask and unit testing in Python, so bare that in mind.

I am writing some unit testing for a backend that I am building for an android app. I am trying to write tests for the functions that communicate with the android client but when I write them, only the definitions of each function I'm testing is registered as covered.

My registration function for example, looks like this:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['POST'])
def register():
    register_args = request.get_json(force=True)
    if not ('username' in register_args and 'email' in register_args and 'password' in register_args):
        abort(406)

    new_username = register_args['username']
    new_email = register_args['email']
    new_password = register_args['password']

    if User.query.filter_by(username=new_username).all() or User.query.filter_by(email=new_email).all():
        abort(406)
    else:
        u = User(username=new_username, email=new_email, password=new_password)
        db.session.add(u)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(u.as_dict())
```

and my test for it looks like this:

```
    def test_registration(self):
        registration_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/register"

        #Password missing
        data = json.dumps({'username': 'Danilzorz', 'email': 'danilzorz@awesome.com'})
        response = requests.post(registration_url, data)
        print("Missing password HTTP-code: " + str(response.status_code))

        #Correct registration
        data = json.dumps({'username': 'Danilzorz', 'email': 'danilzorz@awesome.com', 'password': 'hejhej'})
        response = requests.post(registration_url, data)
        print("Correct registration HTTP-code: " + str(response.status_code))
        self.assertTrue(response.status_code == 200)

        #Username taken
        data = json.dumps({'username': 'Danilzorz', 'email': 'dude@dude.com', 'password': 'hejhej'})
        response = requests.post(registration_url, data)
        print("Incorrect registration HTTP-code: " + str(response.status_code) + "\n")
        self.assertTrue(response.status_code == 406)
```

but only the rows containing the app route and function definition are tested according to both PyCharms built in coverage tester and nosetests.

So my question is, what should I do to get coverage for the rest of the function?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
I am using Python 3.4

Comment: just call register() directly  (dont call it through the url ... or just add a comment to the top to tell coverage that that method is tested via a url call and so coverage should ignore it in the report)  (you will need to use a request context object I believe)

Comment: How would it be done by adding a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to create a request context and call your method directly

```
def test_register():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ctx = app.test_request_context(path="/register?get_arg1=55",method="POST",data={"username":"frank","email":"f@ra.nk","password":"password"})
    ctx.push()
    assert register() == expected_register_output
```

another alternative is to pull the business logic out of the view function

```
 def do_register(username,email,password):
     # // do the actual registration here and return the new User Object
 @app.route("/register",...)
 def register():
     username,password,email = request.form["username"],...
     if do_register(username,email,password):
        return registration_success
     return registration_errors
```

then just call `do_register` on from your test ...

an yet another alternative is to provide comments to tell pycov to ignore that method

```
 @app.route("/register",...)
 def register(): # pragma: no cover
     ....
```

see also http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/excluding.html for more info on excluding some things from coverage

Comment: Thank you! Moving the logic out of these functions gave a much better result!